# Hibernate Return type

Tags: hibernate

Hey guys I know when we are retrieving an integer column from a table in Hibernate the return type is BigDecimal and we specify our type using `<return-scalar column='salary' type='java.lang.Integer'>` in the hbm.xml file.But now I am using annotations and there is no hbm.xml file, so now how can I specify this 
`<return-scalar/>` using annotations in Entity Class.

Answer (score 2):

To return a scalar we have a work around like this

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQueries({
@NamedNativeQuery(name=”COUNT_QUERY”, resultClass = CountDTO.class)})
public class CountDTO {
@Id
@Column(name = “COUNT”)
private Long count;

public Long getCount() {
  return count;
}

public void setCount(Long count) {
  this.count = count;
}
}
```

Comment: I have a salary column that I am trying to retrieve like this

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) { 

Session s1 = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession(); 


Query q1 = s1.createSQLQuery("select salary from person"); 

List<Integer> salaries = q1.list(); 

for(Integer salary : salaries) { 

System.out.println(salary); 
} 
}

Comment: Use a named query and you can use the above implementation.

Comment: I already have this code in my Entity class for age column, its not helping

Comment: Query q1 = s1.createSQLQuery("select age from person").addScalar("age", new IntegerType());